# Div mostrando conteudo ao clicar em botão

Tags: javascript, html, div

to com essa duvida ja pesquisei diversos códigos aqui porem nenhum funcionou, tenho um botão no centro da tela e ao clicar eu quero que mostra um teste especifico que está em uma div, porem o que eu escrevo na div fica na pagina inicial em baixo e o botão não faz nada, então o que eu queria, clicar no botão iniciar teste, e ele chamar essa div, ai dentro dessa div ter outro botão para seguir para o proximo teste e assim por diante .

segue o código

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>TESTE DO FREIO</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">


    <style type="text/css"></style>
</head>

<body>

<label id="counter">0</label>

<div id="teste"></div>

<a class="meubotao" div="#teste01">INICIAR TESTE</a>

<div id="teste01">1. Pressione e solte o pedal de freio do estacionamento varias vezes para checar se a pressão diminui</div>

<div class="footer">
&copy; 2017 PokaYoke Team | Elaborado por Felipe Deolindo
</div>

<script src="js/script.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var sensorValor = '';
    var testEnabled = false;
    var roundedValue = 0;

    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

    setInterval(function () {
        $.get("IOCounter.htm", function (result) {
            $('#counter').text(result.trim());
            sensorValor = $('#counter').text();
        });v
    }, 100);

});

$(function(){
        $(".meubotao").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            el = $(this).data('element');
            $(el).toggle();
        });
    });
```

css

```
body{
    background-color: #373435;
}

#teste{
    width: 1920px;
    height: 1080px;
    background-image: url('../images/background.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.meubotao {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px #000000;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px #000000;
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ffec64), color-stop(1, #ffab23));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffec64 5%, #ffab23 100%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffec64 5%, #ffab23 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #ffec64 5%, #ffab23 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffec64 5%, #ffab23 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffec64 5%, #ffab23 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffec64', endColorstr='#ffab23',GradientType=0);
    background-color:#ffec64;
    -moz-border-radius:15px;
    -webkit-border-radius:15px;
    border-radius:15px;
    border:3px solid #000000;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#333333;
    font-family:Georgia;
    font-size:28px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:20px 50px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #ffffff;
    position:absolute;
        top: 500px;
        left: 700px;
}
.meubotao:hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ffab23), color-stop(1, #ffec64));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffab23 5%, #ffec64 100%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffab23 5%, #ffec64 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #ffab23 5%, #ffec64 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffab23 5%, #ffec64 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffab23 5%, #ffec64 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffab23', endColorstr='#ffec64',GradientType=0);
    background-color:#ffab23;
}
.meubotao:active {
        position:absolute;
        top: 500px;
        left: 700px;
}

.footer {
    position:absolute;
        top: 1080px;
        left: 800px;
}

.teste01 {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: obs: tem um `v` no meio do seu código que com certeza tá causando um erro no load do seu JS, ali no final do setInterval, talvez só isso ja resolva tudo, veja se você errou ao digitar aqui ou esse erro existe na sua aplicação

Comment: Outra coisa, você tá carregando um arquivo `.htm` no get o que não faz muito sentido pra mim uma vez que um arquivo `.htm` não é dinâmico, então qual seria o motivo de você não incluir as instruções do teste direto na sua página ou então em um [tag:JSON]?

Comment: então paulo o arquivo não dinâmico , aquele counter se refere ao contador do teste, só funciona assim não sei porque mais envolve o CLP , ele manda as informações pra esse counter e depois manda pra mim, tirei o v porem deu em nada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## *Resposta inicial porém não completa.

Pelo que entendi, você gostaria de um teste por etapas onde o botão passa para a próxima etapa, por isso criei um exemplo para que você possa utilizar, baseando-se e utilizando o seu código inicial. Sabemos que não irá retratar 100% do seu problema pois eu não tenho o acesso ao arquivo `IOCounter.htm` mas você pode adaptar o código para que o contador também funcione corretamente e então eu editarei posteriormente esta resposta para poder abranger de forma mais concreta a sua pergunta.

Disponibilizei [aqui no jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1xupaac4/) o exemplo para que você possa utilizar.

Comment: Muito bom, muito obrigado mesmo, estava ficando doido já aqui kkkkkk

Comment: o iocounter.htm só tem a seguinte linha :="webdata".counter: ele pega as informações do webserver do PLC e joga na html pra mim

Comment: mas o counter é utilizado só para contar os segundos percorridos durante o teste? se for da pra fazer em javascript também

Comment: mais ou menos, ele pega a pressão em bar do caminhão, eu segui um tutorial do site da siemens pra fazer, nem tentei outra forma, você tem alguma em mente?

Comment: Paulo, nesse mesmo código que você me mandou, se quando eu clicar no botão, ele chamar outro, no caso um tipo proxima teste, porem outro botão, com outro estilo, onde eu modifico no seu codigo? eu troquei o segundo if pela outra id do botão que criei mas não rodou

Comment: é que eu utilizei o mesmo botão, só alterei o texto dele, mas se tu quer além de alterar o texto alterar o estilo vc pode utilizar o `.addClass('sua_classe_css')` no botão lá junto com onde ele muda o texto, e ai nessa `.sua_classe_css` no css vc altera o que for preciso no estilo

Comment: Cara desculpa eu sou meio leigo, to me virando mais ou menos com o que posso aqui eu adiciono o .addClass no lugar da ultima opção .html ?

Comment: e no css não tem que criar uma div pra essa class? ou posso só fazer exmplo .proximo lá que seria o outro botão e editar conforme quero?

Comment: veja eu adicionei uma cor vermelha pros "proxima etapa" https://jsfiddle.net/1xupaac4/1/

Comment: muito obrigado mesmo, salvou esse projeto, valeu mesmo cara

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62404/discussion-between-felipe-deolindo-and-paulo-roberto).

Comment: Paulo vou precisar da sua ajuda novamente, no que você fez para mim, como posso destinguir os testes, exemplo o teste um vai aparecer quando iniciar o teste, porem ao clicar em proximo teste, mostra o 1 junto ao "teste 2", e assim por diante, como eu mostro e escondo isso?
e outra duvida rs, fiz um retangulo para mostrar a pressão dentro dele, mas ele aparece na pagina inicia, sabe me dizer como esconder ele de uma div especifica?